# How to color by groups when doing a funnel plot (in R)?

Tags: r, metafor

I'm creating funnel plots using the metafor package (in R). I want to color the datapoints I'm plotting by groups. I can see that there is a col argument that I could use in the funnel function but it doesn't seem set up for groups (and it doesn't look like there is a group argument).

The best I've been able to find online is to either try to use ggplot (which I would prefer to avoid if possible) or somehow assign colors for the groups before I try to plot (which I'm not sure how to do efficiently). Does anyone have a good solution?

My code is below

```
  res <- rma(as.numeric(effect_size),as.numeric(nonCI_uncertainty_value), data=subsetted3.data, method="DL")

  par(mfrow=c(2,2))

  funnel(res, xlab = "Effect Size", main="Standard Error") + title(sub = paste0(val2," in units of : ", val3), cex.sub = 0.75, font.sub = 3)
```

Comment: I have been able to play around with this more and change the shape of datapoint based on group by creating a numeric values based on the group. The pch argument in funnel is what allows different shapes. Still would prefer color though. Note: I'm not sure if the pch argument is behaving as it should since it only seems to produce two shapes no matter how many groups I have.

Comment: Same question now answered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520122/can-datapoints-be-colored-in-funnel-plot-based-on-category-in-metafor-package-r/