# Can datapoints be colored in Funnel Plot based on category in Metafor package/R?

Tags: r, metafor

Is it possible to color the datapoints in the Funnel plot? I am using the metafor package.

```
 # Load package
 library(metafor)

 # Load data
 data(dat.bcg)

 # Code 
 ex <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, 
 di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="OR",
 slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "), method="FE")

# Funnel plot
funnel(ex, transf = exp, ylab="Test group", xlab="Control")
```

Would it be possible to color the points based on a variable?

Fx blue colored datapoints that represent:

```
dat.bcg$alloc==random
```

Thank you, C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I examined the source code for the `funnel` method and irritatingly, no, you cannot pass a vector of colors to the `col` argument.

An easy workaround is to assign the output of `funnel()` to a variable, which will give you the x and y coordinates of the points in the funnel plot, then plot over the original points on the funnel plot with colored points.

```
# Create vector of colors
my_colors <- c('red','blue')[(dat.bcg$alloc == 'random') + 1]

# Create funnel plot, catching output
funnelplotdata <- funnel(ex, transf = exp, ylab="Test group", xlab="Control")

# Plot over points
with(funnelplotdata, points(x, y, col = my_colors, pch = 19))
```

[image]

Comment: This is the very reason why `funnel()` returns those coordinates. I saw your feature request on GitHub (https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor/issues/23). Will consider adding this option.

Comment: This has now been added as an option to the `metafor` package. For now, you will have to install the devel version of the package to make use of this. See: https://github.com/wviechtb/metafor#installation

Comment: @Wolfgang and qdread Thanks for both of you. I added a related question. If you can help me with that, it will be greatly appreciated. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852514/how-to-plot-untransformed-proportion-in-the-x-axis-of-the-funnel-plot-in-meta-pa)