# How to plot untransformed proportion in the x-axis of the funnel plot in metafor with 3 subgroups legend and colors

Tags: r, plot, metafor, proportions

I am doing a funnel plot of proportion in `metafor` in `R` with color coding based on three different Year categories ( blue, red, and orange).

I want to plot untransformed proportion in the x-axis of the funnel plot with 3 `year` subgroups legend and colors.
The prior [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520122/can-datapoints-be-colored-in-funnel-plot-based-on-category-in-metafor-package-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) helped me in creating this question but did not solve all points yet.

In the following code, I can see only 2 colors (categories) and the same case happened in my actual dataset.

#Here is my code and data sample:

```
d<-read.table(text="ID study year d.asp n.asp d.plac n.plac
1  MRC-1 1974    49   615     67    624
2    CDP 1976    44   758     64    771
3  MRC-2 1979   102   832    126    850
4   GASP 1979    32   317     38    309
5  PARIS 1980    85   810     52    406
6   AMIS 1980   246  2267    219   2257
7 ISIS-2 1988  1570  8587   1720   8600
8  IMRC-2 1973   12   888    176    8950
9   IGASP 1972    12   399     48    209
10  IPARIS 1970    65   899     12    706
11  IIMRC-1 1973    19   315     27    124", sep="", header=T)


d$year_3gps<-"Before 1973"
d$year_3gps[ d$year  >=1973 & d$year <1980 ]<-"Year 1973 - 1979"
d$year_3gps[ d$year  >=1980 ]<-"Year 1980 or after"
addmargins(table(d$year_3gps))

m1 <- rma(xi=d.plac, ni=n.plac, data=d, measure="PLO",
          #slab=paste(author, year, sep=", "), 
          method="FE")

# Create a vector of colors
my_colors <- c("blue", "red","orange4")[(d$year_3gps == "Before 1973") + 1]

# Create funnel plot, catching output
funnelplotdata <- funnel(m1, atransf = exp, ylab="Standered error", xlab="Proportion")
legend(-4.1, 0,  c("Before 1973","Year 1973 - 1979", "Year 1980 or after"  ),
       fill = c("blue", "red","orange4"))

# Plot over points
with(funnelplotdata, points(x, y, col = my_colors, pch = 19))
```

Here is the resulting plot that is missing the orange dots although they are not under the legend:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your color vector is incorrect, try this:

```
# Create a vector of colors
my_colors <- c("blue", "red", "orange4")[as.factor(d$year_3gps)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works. Appreciate it. Upvoted. It will be helpful if you can guide me on a similar question `meta` published here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76852514/how-to-plot-untransformed-proportion-in-the-x-axis-of-the-funnel-plot-in-meta-pa/76852921#76852921)